# l-value required as left operand of assignment error - but why?

Tags: c

In general I know why you get this error, but I'm a little confused in this particular instance...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* mystrncpy(char* dst, const char* src, size_t n) {
    char* temp = dst;

    while (n-- > 0 && (*temp = *src)) {
        temp++;
        src++;
    }

    return dst;
}

int main() {
    const char* str = "Hello World!";
    char buf[50];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    mystrncpy(buf, str, sizeof(buf));
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

The code above works great, but if I remove the extra set of brackets changing the while loop to:

```
while (n-- > 0 && *temp = *src)
```

Then I get the error.  I guess it's something about operator precedence but I'm a little baffled.  Can someone explain what that while loop alteration does to make this compiler error appear?

Comment: If you already suspect operator precedence issues, what's stopping you from looking up the precedence rules of the operators in your expression?

Comment: @KerrekSB sometimes a push goes a long way :).

Comment: Honestly, I'm very accustomed to C++ and find sometimes that when I look at real C code I take some things for granted, so I just prefer to ask in case there's any "extra tidbits" I might miss by making an assumption.  For example, the whole concept of how to use the struct keyword in C was messing with my mind recently - and how you can typedef a struct with the same name as the struct without a conflict arising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's about precedence.

`=` has lower precedence than `&&`. Therefore, the latter case parses as:

```
while ((n-- > 0 && *temp) = *src)
```

And of course `(n-- > 0 && *temp)` is not an l-value.

<strike>Are you sure you didn't intend to use `==` instead of `=`?</strike>

Comment: I agree with the answer but yes he should use `=` as he is assigning characters not comparing them.  Still I think your intention is to explain the issue so +1.

Answer (score 4):

```
    n-- > 0 && *temp = *src
```

```
                           =
                          / \
                         &&  *src
                        /  \
                       >    *temp
                      / \
                    n--  0
```

Comment: Thank you  --  Don't be afraid of using too many parenthesis :)

Answer (score 2):

Assignment has very low [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence), so

```
n-- > 0 && *temp = *src
```

is equivalent to

```
(n-- > 0 && *temp) = *src
```

which isn't valid C.

Answer (score 0):

[Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  The && operator is in position 13 and = is 16.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator has really low precedence, so it's like you're trying to assign to the result of `n-- > 0 && *temp`, which is obviously not an lvalue.